# How to create foreign key by Laravel migration?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How can we make a `referenced key` and `foreign key` in `laravel` by `migrations`.
Think I have two migration files in database directory in laravel, both of them create a different table in my database.
the first migration creates a table that is for posts which has a column in the name of Id.
the second migration create comments table that has a column in the name of post_id. Now `the Id column in posts table is referenced key` and the `post_id in comments table is foreign key`, how can I connect these two columns together?

Comment: Have you tried the docs? [Follow the link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would be better to set `unsignedInteger` for foreign key type

```
$table->unsignedInteger('category_id')->nullable();

$table->foreign('category_id')
       ->references('id')
       ->on('categories')
       ->onUpdate('cascade')
       ->onDelete('some action');;
```

Answer (score 4):

Take the example where you have a users table and a user_address table. A user can have many addresses and an address belongs to a user.

Default user table

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

user_addresses table with user_id as the foreign key

```
  Schema::create('user_addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id'); // by default the primary key is set to unsigned big integer
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id'); //associate the address with a user
            $table->text('address');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('country');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

After defining the migrations, next step is to define the relationship in their respective model classes

In the User Model, add

```
public function address(){
        return $this->hasMany(UserAddress::class );
    }
```

And in the UserAddress Model, add

```
 public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you use like this.

```
$table->integer('userId')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('userId')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to create a foreign key constraint for a table that references the 'id' column on a 'users' table for example. For a better developer experience, you can write it in this way:

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')
  ->constrained('users')
  ->onUpdate('cascade')
  ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```