# How to declare a foreign key in laravel

Tags: laravel, database, foreign-keys

So im trying to connect 2 tables (users,drawing) in laravel,all of the other columns are being created,the only thing the compiler has problems with is the foreign key,
this is the code for both of the tables

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id('users_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

```php
    Schema::create('drawings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('drawings_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('canvas_size');
        $table->foreign('users_id')
        ->references('users_id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and this is the error I get when trying the command(php artisan migrate)

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'users_id' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `drawings` add constraint `drawings_users_id_foreign` foreign key (`users_id`) references `users` (`users_id`) on delete cascade)
```

I tried different methods, the old one and new one,neither is working for me,can you please help, also I'm using OpenServer for the database

Solution:My problem was that I was using $table->unsignedInteger('users_id')->nullable();
instead of             $table->unsignedBigInteger('users_id')->nullable();
for the users_id,sorry guys my bad

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create foreign key by Laravel migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180314/how-to-create-foreign-key-by-laravel-migration)

Comment: I tried it but another error appear,l error: 3780 Referencing column 'users_id' and referenced column 'users_id' in foreign key constraint 'drawings_users_id_foreign' are incompatible

Comment: I also tried changing the primary key name of the user table to 'id',same error

Comment: Add `$table->unsignedBigInteger("users_id")->nullable();` **before** your `drawings` migration's foreign key reference definition.

Comment: Yes,I did that but still no

Comment: Try deleting/dropping the `drawings` table and re-running the `drawing` table creation migration.

Comment: Please, always share your current Laravel framework version as well.

Comment: In addition, what do you mean by *"Yes, I did that but still no"*? That's a vague statement. An error message/explicit unexpected behavior would be more helpful.

Comment: the version is Laravel Framework 9.37.0

Comment: the error of the solution you proposed is on the second comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't added the **user_id column** in **drawings table**.

I will rewrite the two migration files according to the best practice:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id(); // You have to leave the primary key "id" so leave this empty
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});

    Schema::create('drawings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();// You have to leave the primary key "id" so leave this empty
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('canvas_size');
        // You have to add the foreign key column first
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id'); // Best to make it single
        $table->foreign('user_id')
         ->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: Every time you think you want to post an answer to a new question, the first thing you should do is take 5 or 10 minutes to search Stack Overflow (via Google search) and hunt aggressively for duplicate pages that already exist. If you find a duplicate that resolves the new question, please vote to close the new question. If you have something unique and valuable to add to the older page, please post your advice there. By ignoring pre-existing content, researchers have a harder time finding and comparing relevant insights on a given topic.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the problem with my answer?

Comment: I tried leaving the name from $table->id empty but still this error from the second comment (  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'users_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'drawings_users_id_foreign' are incompatible. (SQL: alter table `drawings` add constraint `drawings_users_id_foreign` foreign key (`users_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade))

Comment: thanks mate,I just did see the unsignedBigInteger instead of unsignedInteger I was using